# HTML5 Audio Player Not Working Properly with Full Controls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, audio, html5-audio

I am showing recordings in table with play option.

When user presses on play option an HTML5 Media Player is popped up with recording user selected to play.

I am getting some strange behavior that when user clicks on first record, media player works fine with all controls. As you can see in the image below:
[image]

And when user select the play option of records other than first one on table, then media player is shown but its control don't work properly but user can still hear recording.

As you can see in the image below that recording is being played but volume, time and pause/resume controls are disabled.

[image]

Below you can see the code snippet which executes each time user presses the play option to listen the recording:

```html
 <tr ng-model="recording" ng-show="call.id === rowId && actionType === 'play'">
            <td colspan="8" class="long">
                <span class="ion-close btn btn-default pull-right" ng-click="selectRow(call.id, 'play')"></span>
                <div align="center">
                    <audio id="playarea" controls ng-src="{{audio_src}}" style="width: 100%; background-color: #F9F9F9">
                        Your browser does not support the audio tag.
                    </audio>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

**P.S.** I am using AngularJS on Backend, I can share that code as well if desired. Thanks